# How can I get my search form to search for product categories?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, search-form

I'm using the default Woocommerce search bar (get_searchform) on my site using the code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form">

  <div class="postcode-search col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">

    <input type='textbox' name="s" class="form-control form-inline" style="display: inline;" id="item-search" value="<?php the_search_query();?>" placeholder="Enter your postcode"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="item-search-btn"><span class="">find stores</span></button>
    </span>

    <?php
      if ( function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_search' ) ) {
        echo woocommerce_product_search( array( 'limit' => 40 ) );
      }
    ?>

  </div>

</form>
```

It successfully displays the results for all my Woocommerce products but I want it to be used for users to search for product categories only therefore only showing parent product categories and not products. 
Does anyone know how I can alter the code above to achieve this?
All suggestions are very welcome and thank you in advance!